# メンテナンスのお知らせ：12月13日 (水) 10:00 〜 JST

Tags: 討議

[Meta Stack Exchange](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/395198/314875) に記載されている通り、日本時間で 2023 年 12 月 13 日（水）の午前 10 時頃から約 1 時間メンテナンスが予定されています。この期間中、サイトは読み取り専用モードとなり、質問/回答/コメントの投稿や編集、投票は行えません。また、チャットも利用できません。ご不便をおかけしますがどうぞよろしくお願いいたします。